# How to add spinner for loading to fetch API from MongoDB?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb

**Custom hook .js**

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const UseHook = () => {
    const [items,setItems]=useState([]);
    useEffect(()=>{
        fetch('https://agile-brushlands-55517.herokuapp.com/inventory')
        .then(res=>res.json())
        .then(data=>setItems(data))
      },[])
      return[items,setItems]
};

export default UseHook;
```

**fetch API**

```
const [items]=UseHook([])
   
return (
  <div className='container'>
    <h1>Inventory Items</h1>
    <div className='row g-4'>
      {           
        items?.slice(0,6).map(item=><Item key={item._id} item={item}></Item>)
      }
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: I feel like it would be better if you could have provided a better and more detailed explanation. But, from this question, what I could suggest is instead of using `[]` as the initial state use `null` something like: `const [items,setItems]=useState(null);` and if there is no `items` then you can show `Loading` components ex: `if(!items){ <Loading /> }` where `Loading` is another separate component with spinner.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.